# Foreach for 3 variables in an array

Tags: php, cakephp

I am trying to loop three variables inside an array with a foreach loop.

My model to get my array is this

```
function pieChart($limit = null, $conditions = null) {
    //Get Data for PieChart
    $this->RecordDrug->virtualFields['sum'] ='COUNT(*)';
    $records = array();
    $records=$this->RecordDrug->find('list',
        array(
            'conditions' => $conditions,
            'fields' => array( 'Drug.drug', 'sum', 'Record.unit'),
            'order' => array('sum' => 'desc'),
            'limit' => $limit,
            'contain' => array( 'Drug', 'Record' ),
            'group'  => 'Drug.Drug'
            ));
    debug($records);
    return $records;
}
```

My debug gives me this:

```
//Record.unit = a
//Drug.drug = b,
//sum = c,

array(
  'a' => array(
     'b' => 'c'
   )
)
```

I want to be able to echo a, b , and 200 inside a foreach loop. How is that possible?

Comment: what is `a` and `b` here?

Comment: Sorry, just edited OP to define those

Answer (score 0):

It looks your array is going 2 dimensions deep.. It's not usually in good practice to have nested foreach loops.. How about trying this:

```
foreach ($Array AS $Arr1_Values){
  if (is_array($Arr1_Values)){
    foreach ($Arr1_Values AS $Arr1_Nest)){
       echo $Arr1_Nest;
     }
  }else{
    echo $Arr1_Values;
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is I need to echo the variables in a specific way. And it doesn't seem like I can do that with your method, or can I? Also, if it's not good practice, do you mind telling me a better method so I can google it and learn it?